# TCP/IP Echo-Client hang

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

Just started C networking using [TCP/IP Sockets in C: Practical Guide for Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123745403). I have followed the code example in the book:

```
#include <stdio.h> //for printf and fprintf
#include <sys/socket.h> // for socket() , connect(),send(), and recv()
#include <arpa/inet.h> //for sockaddr_in and inet_addr()
#include <stdlib.h> //for atoi()
#include <string.h> //for memset()
#include <unistd.h> //for close()

#define RCVBUFSIZE 32 //size of recieve  buffer

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage); //error handling function

int main (int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sock; /*SOcket descriptor*/
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /*Echo server address*/
    unsigned short echoServPort; /*Echo server port*/
    char *servIP; /*Server IP address (dotted quad)*/
    char *echoString; /*string to send to echo server*/
    char echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE]; /*Buffer for echo string*/
    unsigned int echoStringLen; /*Length of string to echo*/
    int bytesRcvd , totalBytesRcvd; /*Bytes read in single recv() and total bytes read*/

    if( (argc < 3) || (argc > 4) ) /*Test for correct number of arguments */
    {
        fprintf(stderr , "Usage: %s <Server IP> <Echo Word> [<Echo Port>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    servIP = argv[1]; /*first arg: server IP address (dotted quad)*/
    echoString = argv[2]; /*Second arg: string echo*/

    if(argc == 4)
        echoServPort = atoi(argv[3]); /*Use given port, if any*/
    else
        echoServPort = 7; /*7 is the well-known port for the echo service*/

    /*Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP*/
    if( (sock = socket(PF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0 )
        DieWithError("Connect() failed");

    /*COnstruct the server address structure*/
    memset(&echoServAddr , 0 , sizeof(echoServAddr)); /*zero out structure*/
    echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; /*Internet address family*/
    echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP); /*Server IP address*/
    echoServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort); /*Server port*/

    /*Establish the connection the echo server*/
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr , sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
        DieWithError("send() sent a differnt number of bytes than expected");

    /*Recieve the same string back from the server*/
    totalBytesRcvd = 0;
    printf("Recieved: "); /*setup to print the echoed string*/
    while(totalBytesRcvd < echoStringLen)
    {
        /* Recieve up to the bufffer size (minus 1 to leave space for a null terminator)
           bytes from the sender*/
        if( (bytesRcvd = recv(sock , echoBuffer , RCVBUFSIZE - 1, 0)) <=0)
            DieWithError("recv() failed or connection closed prematurely");
        totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd; /*Keep tally of total bytes*/
        echoBuffer[bytesRcvd] = '\0'; /*Terminate the string*/
        printf(echoBuffer); /*Print the echo buffer*/
    }

    printf("\n"); /*Print a final linefeed*/
    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage)
{   perror(errorMessage);
    exit(1);
}
```

Book's code (unable to copy from the book as i have the legit physical copy but here is the link to the free online pdf version) [book](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/136904/TCP%7CIP_Sockets_in_C:_Practical_Guide_for_Programmers.pdf) It's the first peice of code in the book which is the

> TCPEchoClient.c

The book then tells me to compile and execute the program with these arguments:

> If we 
>   compile 
>   this 
>   application 
>   as 
>   TCPEchoClient, 
>   we 
>   can 
>   communicate 
>   with 
>   an 
>   echo 
>   server 
>   with 
>   Internet 
>   address 
>   169.1.1.1 
>   as 
>   follows: 
>   % TCPEchoClient 
>   169. 
>   i. i. 
>   I  "Echo 
>   this!" 
>   Received' 
>   Echo 
>   this!

However when i use these arguments from the book, my program just hangs when i run it. I'm confused as to why this is occurring? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The IP address you provide should of course be the address of the host where you run the server. You *are* running the server somewhere?

Comment: Please indent your code if your expect others to read it.

Comment: i will go over and indent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh and you seem to have forgotten something very important when you copied the code: Actually *sending* something to the server.

Somewhere between

```
if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr , sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
```

and the very next line

```
DieWithError("send() sent a differnt number of bytes than expected");
```

you seem to be missing the actual code to send the data to the server.

Since you don't send anything the server will just wait patiently with its `recv` call. Meanwhile you are stuck in your own `recv` call waiting for a reply that never happens. This leads to a *deadlock*, where both the server and the client wait for the other peer to send something.